# Advanced Euclidean Geometry Problems Books for school level

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry, problem-solving, plane-geometry

I have searched on Google, but it's hard to know how to search so as to find an advanced school level geometry problems book, like [the one of Sharygin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/5030001808) ([freely available copy](https://www.isinj.com/mt-aime/Problems%20in%20Plane%20Geometry%20-%20Sharygin%20(MIR,1982).pdf)).

Could you please recommend me some books to practice problem solving in plane geometry for school teachers and school pupils?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I did the book called" A school Geometry " by H.S. Hall and F.H.Stevens , it is for grade 6 and above level students I guess. It starts with axioms , and then basic definitions like Parallel lines , etc and then areas and all . It also has some basic 3d geo in the last 5 . Another one is intro to geometry by AOPS.